# access laptop hard drive via USB?

Tags: laptop, hard-drive, usb

The motherboard on my laptop has died, and I want to get some files off its SATA hard drive. I have a desktop machine - is there some kind of housing I can put the hard drive into and then access it via USB?

Answer (score 1):

Laptop SATA hard drives use same interface as desktop SATA hard drives. You could just plug it into your desktop computer, if it uses SATA, without the need to buy any adapter. If you don't want to open your computer, there are lots of SATA-> USB adapters. For example [this](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16812232002) one (first result on Google for "SATA to USB adapter" for me).